# How do I add android drawables?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-drawable

I'm working on an android navigation drawer activity and I want to change the logos in the `activity_main_drawer` file.
Is there any good way to add one of the default drawables to the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default drawables?

You mean `android.R.drawable.*`? That's not everything, but you can download icons from https://materialdesignicons.com

Then drop them into `res/drawable` for the different aspect ratios of devices.